# TensorFlow the variable cant be initialized

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,32,32,3])
y=tf.placeholder(tf.int64,[None])
is_training=tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

def simple_model(X,y):

    Wconv1=tf.get_variable("Wconv1",shape=[7,7,3,32],use_resource=True)
    bconv1=tf.get_variable('bconv1',shape=[32])
    W1=tf.get_variable('W1',shape=[5408,10])
    b1=tf.get_variable('b1',shape=[10])

    a1=tf.nn.conv2d(X,Wconv1,[1,2,2,1],'VALID')+bconv1
    h1=tf.nn.relu(a1)

    h1_flat=tf.reshape(h1,[-1,5408])
    y_out=tf.matmul(h1_flat,W1)+b1
    return y_out

init=tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    sess.run(simple_model(X,y),feed_dict={X:X_train,y:y_train})
```

error is

> PreconditionError Attempting to use uninitialized variable `Wconv1`

I dont know what wrong with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.global_variables_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables_initializer) makes an initialization op for all the global variables created **up to that point**. This means that if you create other variables later, they will not be initialized by the operation. This is because variable initializers just hold a list of the variables they have to initialize, and this does not change as you add more variables (in fact, `tf.global_variables_initializer()` is just a shortcut for `tf.variables_initializer(tf.global_variables())` or `tf.variables_initializer(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES))`). In your case, the variables are being created in the second call to `sess.run`, after you create `init` earlier. You need to create the initialization operation *after* you have created your model with the variables:

```
X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,32,32,3])
y=tf.placeholder(tf.int64,[None])
is_training=tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

def simple_model(X,y):

    Wconv1=tf.get_variable("Wconv1",shape=[7,7,3,32],use_resource=True)
    bconv1=tf.get_variable('bconv1',shape=[32])
    W1=tf.get_variable('W1',shape=[5408,10])
    b1=tf.get_variable('b1',shape=[10])

    a1=tf.nn.conv2d(X,Wconv1,[1,2,2,1],'VALID')+bconv1
    h1=tf.nn.relu(a1)

    h1_flat=tf.reshape(h1,[-1,5408])
    y_out=tf.matmul(h1_flat,W1)+b1
    return y_out

my_model = simple_model(X,y)
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    sess.run(my_model, feed_dict={X:X_train,y:y_train})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving this problem. This problem was puzzling me for one week.